# Fabric stuck at "We're processing the uploaded dSYM(s). Please check back in a few minutes for the status."

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric to monitor crash on my iOS apps. I got an error that I am missing dSYM file. Using the information give in subtitle xarchives in the guide https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html I uploaded a dSYM file.

Now it is stuck at "We're processing the uploaded dSYM(s). Please check back in a few minutes for the status." How to solve this issue ?

Comment: did you zip it ?